# Error when uploading a pdf file on wiki

Tags: pdf, mime-types, wiki

I want to upload a pdf file on my wiki page but i keep getting an error that says

> Extension ".pdf--" does not correspond to the MIME type given in the file (application / pdf).

I have searched on the internet but can't quite find a solution to it. Please help and I'm new to this stuff so sorry if this is really easy.

Edit: picture of the filename
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gopaC.png

Comment: Are you sure your file extension is only ".pdf" and not ".pdf--"?

Comment: Yes, look at the picture in the edit.

Comment: What wiki software is this?